# Simple flex program doesn't execute the lines in main()

Tags: c, flex-lexer

```
%option noyywrap

%{ 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>

int chars=0, lines=0;
%}

binary  [01]+

%%

{binary}    {ECHO; printf("\n"); chars++; }
\n   {lines++; chars++;}

%%

int main() { 
yylex();
printf(" %d chars and %d lines\n", chars, lines);
return 0;
}
```

I have written this and i want it to print every 0 and 1 and also print how many characters and lines i've written on the console. it does echo the 1s and 0s but nothing in the main() is printed. why?

Comment: How are you providing input to this program? Perhaps the `printf` is never reached because `yylex` isn't returning?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I agree - I'm wondering whether they're just running the program interactively and never pressing CTRL+D or something like that.

Comment: When I compile the code and run it on a file: `flex fl37.l; gcc -o fl37 lex.yy.c` and then run it: `./fl37 < data` where `data` contains some lines, it works for me.  The file contained three lines: `010101`, `2345` and `abcd`; the output was `010101` and 
`2345abcd 4 chars and 3 lines`.  Tested on a Mac (macOS Sierra 12.10.1, GCC 6.2.0, Flex 2.3.35).  Note that the '4 chars' includes a count of 1 for all of `010101`, and then one for each of 3 newlines.  The three lines are counted correctly.  You need to show how you're running the code and the input data and the actual output ([MCVE]).

Answer (score 0):

When you run your code, you're probably running it interactively. By default, flex sets the input stream to *stdin*, so it hangs in what's called 'interactive mode', which allows you to manually enter the input directly to the program.

The convention most programs use (and flex is no exception) is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to end interactive mode input. When you've typed your input, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> and your program should finish executing as expected.

Another way to feed input into your program would be via a pipe or a file. For instance,

```
echo -e "Hello\nthere" | ./my-program
```

or

```
./my-program < some-file.txt
```

in which case the end of the file (what is sent when you manually hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> in interactive mode) is sent to your program when it has finished reading the file's contents.